# Total change of a signal overtime

Tags: signal-processing

I have some signals whose analytic type I do not know. I can only sample them  every 0.1 secs. I want to pick that signal that changes as little as possible. For example, between sin2t and sint I would like to pick sint. What characteristic of the signals can I look for?

Comment: Perhaps total variation.

Comment: yes,you are right!Thanks!

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)